# SQL ERROR [1054] [42S22]: Unknown column 't1.d' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(date_add('2020-07-31', interval t1.generate_series day), '%Y-%m-%d') as 'date_range'
FROM (
SELECT 0 generate_series FROM DUAL WHERE (@num:=1-1)*0 UNION ALL
SELECT @num:=@num+1 FROM `information_schema`.COLUMNS LIMIT 13
) as t1
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m-%d') as order_date, count(*) FROM users WHERE created_at >= "2022-8-1 00:00:00" group by order_date
) as t2
ON t1.date_range = t2.order_date;
```

Once run the above SQL on MySQL 8.0.23, this error occured.

```
SQL ERROR [1054] [42S22]: Unknown column 't1.d' in 'on clause'
```

But it was successed if devided by line 6; t1 and run them.

How should I do?

Comment: The error message does not come from the published code. Also please explain what you are trying to do rather than have us attempt to reverse engineer from non working code.

Comment: Are we missing something ? I see no `t1.d` at all in your query .

Comment: #1. `t1` contains only one column named `generate_series`. #2. Your query does not mention `t1.d` anywhere.

Comment: If your MySQL version is 8+ then use recursive CTE for numbers (but the best way - dates) list generation instead of user-defined variable.

Answer (score 0):

The column you are trying to use on Clause does not exist that is why it gives an error on t1. You should first make sure that t1.date_range is returned in t1 select.

Comment: I note that date_range is an alias in the outer select but not in the t1 sub-query.